# How to extract and manipulate the hour of an Airflow DAG execution date as a variable?

Tags: python, airflow, jinja2

How can I extract the hour of an Airflow DAG execution date as a variable and perform manipulations on it (such as multiplication by a factor or subtracting from a value) while ensuring that the DAG can be rerun with a different execution date? I currently write

`EXEC_HOUR = '{{ execution_date.strftime("%H") }}'`

to extract the hour as a variable, but I cannot perform any logic with it.

so for example I can not do:
`NEW_VAR = EXEC_HOUR * -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way that i found to do it is to put the logic in a method use it in a PythonOperator like that:

```
    my_logic_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='logic_task',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=logic_method,
        dag=dag
    )
```

when the method is something like that:

```
def logic_method(**kwargs):
    execution_date = kwargs['execution_date']
    return -execution_date.hour if execution_date.hour < 12 else 24 - execution_date.hour
```

after that you can create a variable `MY_ANSWER` like that:

```
MY_ANSWER = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='logic_task') }}"
```

and pass it in your KubernetesPodOperator arguments.

Without using PythonOperator the argument it will look like this:

```
[<function logic_method at 0xffff937ee830>]
```